# Is this the Taylor expansion of a known function?

Tags: complex-analysis, taylor-expansion

Consider the following (real or complex) function $f(x)$ defined for $|x|<1$ by the Taylor series:

$$f(x) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}x^{n^2}=1+x+x^4+x^9+x^{16}+\dots$$

Is this the Taylor expansion of a known function or a function that can be written in terms of known functions? It is obviously analytic inside the complex unit circle, and I suspect with a singularity (perhaps a pole) at $x=1$. Any ideas about this function and some of its properties?

Comment: Ever heard of Jacobi Theta functions?

Comment: Pretty sure this is going to be a Lacunary Series, and thus the unit circle is going to be the natural boundry. This means no analytic continuation past the unit circle.